# Can a memory leak cause my process to get killed?

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

This is a short description of my problem :

**Context :**

Hardware : Toradex Colibri VF61

Distribution : Angstrom v2014.12

Kernel release : 4.0.2-v2

Software language : Qt/C++

**Problem :**
I develop an application which needs to run at least 2 weeks on an embedded product. My problem is that my process runs for 5 days with a small memory leak, that I monitore whit "Top", and then it gets killed.
My process was turned into a zombie, as Top told me.

**Attempt number 1 :**
I tried to correct the memory leak with Valgrind, but some "probably" leaks are in libraries I use in my program (many are malloc). It's a very big work to understand all of the librairies and it's not the goal.

I think the memory leak is about 1% of memory lost per day, so 15% lost in 2 weeks. This kind of leak is acceptable for me, because the process will not run after 2 weeks, and the embedded system is dedicated for this process, I don't have any other big process running on the machine. The RAM monitoring shows that the process takes 30% of ressources, so estimated to 45% two weeks later.

**Attempt number 2 :**
I inquired about memory management under Linux and learned about OOM-Killer. I deduced that OOM-Killer propably felt that my process had been running for too long with a memory leak and killed it.
So I set the variable "oom_score_adj" of my process to -1000 to prevent OOM-Killer from killing my process and I tried again to run for long time with my memory leak.
But this time my process was turned into "sleeping" and not killed but unusable. The sleeping state was associated to an error message "Error in './app': malloc(): memory corruption (fast) : 0x72518ddf". I precise that I have zero malloc in my code, only in librairies I use.

**Questions :**

Do you think it's possible that a process like OOM-Killer could turn my process into zombie because I have a memory leak and my program has been running for a long time ?

Do you think it's possible that Linux turn my process into sleeping mode because the leak has filled up the memory allocated to the process ?

Comment: You may have a `ulimit` or similar construct defined, this is another method by which the OS may decide your process needs terminating

Comment: FWIW `new` can (and does in many implementations) call `malloc` so if you have calls to `new` you probably have calls to `malloc`.  Many standard containers will also have calls to `malloc` for their dynamic allocation as well

Comment: Does Valgrind show any invalid memory access? If it is there, I will doubt it more.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first  gives a detailed idea about which process might be killed by OOM killer first. Check the /proc/pid/oom_score_adj .  Did you see any logs in syslog/dmesg that the OOM killer killed your application ? If not, then it's a memory corruption that caused the issue not the OOM killer.

Comment: I do not have a log in syslog/dmesg.

What I understand of the problem is that the process makes a memory allocation request at launch, but that my memory leak fills this allocated memory. When it is full, something in my software comes to create a new object, then a malloc is called to reserve memory, but there is no space available, the malloc is therefore outside the allocated area and therefore in a forbidden zone. Linux puts the process to sleep while waiting to assign a new memory zone to it and things get stuck in this state.

Do I understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question, the OOM Killer will kill one or more processes following the oom_score (high memory consumption, less important for system, ..) in case of very less memory left for the system. So if the OOM Killer kills a child process of your main process, this will turn your main process to zombie.

To your second question, Linux put a process to sleeping state, if the resources for this certain process are not available. But in your case if there is memory leakage and the process consumes lot of memory then the process will be rather killed then put in sleeping state.

Are you using UART for your Application?

By the way, there is also a Toradex Community, where engineers can directly answers your questions.

Best regards, Jaski

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jaski. I tried again to do a test with a "oom_score_adj" set to -1000 and the debugger GDB. The result is that the process worked longer, about 6 days, but it was still put in "sleep", and I had no information by debugging it.

Yes I use the UART in my application, it poses a problem?

What can I try as a test to investigate the problem?

Comment: Your process will be put to sleep mode, if there is memory leakage and after some time, there is not enough memory free. So you need to fix the memory leakage. Concerning Uart, please look in Toradex Community.